# Internal Thread vs External Thread in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I read an [Artcle](http://www.learncsharptutorial.com/thready-safely-csharp.php) about thread safty's technique in c#, it said that

> Lock or Monitor is one and same it works with internal threads generated by an application. Lock or monitor does not have control over external threads.

i  didn't understand what are `Internal thread` and `External therad`? what does it means?

Comment: They don't have any explicit meaning. But I *think* what the article is trying to say is that : `lock` / `Monitor` aren't magic - they can only influence threads that choose to use them, and the only threads that are going to choose to use them are the threads in your application.

Comment: From what I can deduce from the article - the internal and external threads is not very good definition of threads which belong to a given process and those which don't. The confusion is also imposed by the fact a process seems to be denoted by "application" term in the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your quote *"internal threads generated by an application"* From later on in the article *"External threads basically coming from outside of an application"*

Internal threads, in this context, are created by the application itself - so Lock & Monitor could be used allow synchronisation of access to a resource by different threads within a single application.

External threads are created by other applications - so Mutex & Semaphore could be used to allow synchronisation of access to a resource by different applications.

Comment: Thanks for answering, there is a situation that we have both Internal and External thread? if ture, we should use which one of (Mutex or Lock/monitor)?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by _"there is a situation that we have both Internal and External thread"_. All .net applications are going to have "internal" threads - if you have multiple applications running together - then the "internal" threads for each application are "external" to the other applications. If you are locking something which can only be accessed within an application - then Lock/Monitor are suitable. If you are trying to lock something common to multiple applications that you are writing - then Mutex/Semaphore would be suitable.

Comment: if i use semaphore just for internal theread. Ia it some thing goes wrong  or not?

Comment: You can use Mutex/Semaphore for internal threads if you wish - nothing will go wrong. What you may find though, if you are performing many locking operations, they are slightly slower than Lock?Monitor so you get a slight performance hit.